# Swapping two text box values

Tags: jquery

I have two text box values:-

```
var pickup = $('#txt-pickup');
var destination = $('#txt-destination');
```

and I want to swap the two values as follows:-

```
pickup.val(destination.val());
destination.val(pickup.val());
```

However, the above will always set both values as the same value. (same as the destination value)

Is there a way of changing both of these at the same time?

Comment: Use a temp variable, that's basic

Comment: Javascript is not _that_ asynchronous!

Comment: @C-link, I have down-voted. this is taught in the first week of programming lesson and its not specific to a language or only applicable to programming

Comment: @Satpal So you are downvoting everybody because they have the balls to ask a question to get smarter?

Thats a sh*tty attitude if you ask me!

Comment: @JoakimM, I have downvoted as OP doesn't show any research effort. Had  he would have got result and I want to re-quote `this is taught in the first week of programming lesson and its not specific to a language or only applicable to programming` I have balls to says I have downvoted. Search for `Swapping two text box values` you will get result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle for you:

```
<input id="txt-pickup" type="text"/>
<input id="txt-destination" type="text"/>
<input id="change" type="button" value="Swap"/>

$(document).ready(function (){

    $("#change").on('click',function(){
        var pickup = $('#txt-pickup').val();
        $('#txt-pickup').val($('#txt-destination').val());
        $('#txt-destination').val(pickup);


    });

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mQS8N/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this worked on me

```html
<div>
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<input type="text" id="text2"/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="swap"/>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").click(function()
  {
    var a = $("#text1").val();
    $("#text1").val($("#text2").val());
    $("#text2").val(a);

  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Genius. Thank for this, tried many other lines of code before finding your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Store the value in the variable than assign it to the another textbox.

```
var pickup = $('#txt-pickup'),
    destination = $('#txt-destination');

var d_val = destination.val(); //cache value of destination
destination.val(pickup.val()); //change value of destination to pickup.val()
pickup.val(d_val); //change value of pickup to cached value of destination
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of any of these two textbox in a variable and then set this variable as the value of the other textbox:

```
var tmp = $('#txt-pickup').val();
pickup.val(destination.val());
destination.val(tmp);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4kzZZ/)**