# How to change text by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down menu containing 4 drop down texts  which should change when clicking on main menu. How can it be done by java script?

eg: when i click department or status the grey background section text change to Department or status

Screenshot

[image]

```css
.candidates_header_btns {
  padding: 0px;
}

.candidates_header_btns>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.add_candidates {
  background: #124c56;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.add_candidates:hover,
.add_candidates:focus {
  color: #e4e4e4;
}

.date_button {
  background: #8b8c8b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}

.date_button:hover,
.date_button:focus {
  color: #e4e4e4;
}

.add_candidates_dropdown {
  background: #18505a;
  padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.add_candidates_dropdown>li {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.add_candidates_dropdown>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 15px;
  border-width: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #124c56 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}

.date_dropdown {
  padding: 0;
}

.date_dropdown>li {
  text-align: right;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  min-width: 130px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.date_dropdown>li>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.date_dropdown>li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.date_dropdown>li>a:hover,
.date_dropdown>li>a:focus {
  color: #eb3c29;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="candidates_header_btns">
  <li><a class="add_candidates" href="create-a-new-job.html"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Jobs</a></li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="date_button">Custom</a>
    <ul class="add_candidates_dropdown date_dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Department</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use the idea of swap. Like http://stackoverflow.com/a/23264937/4229270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$(".date_dropdown a").on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".date_button").html($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this bit of code to change the text on click

```
$('.add_candidates_dropdown li a').click(function() {
  $('.date_button').text($(this).text())
})
```

```js
$('.add_candidates_dropdown li a').click(function() {
  $('.date_button').text($(this).text())
})
```

```css
.candidates_header_btns {
  padding: 0px;
}

.candidates_header_btns>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.add_candidates {
  background: #124c56;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.add_candidates:hover,
.add_candidates:focus {
  color: #e4e4e4;
}

.date_button {
  background: #8b8c8b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}

.date_button:hover,
.date_button:focus {
  color: #e4e4e4;
}

.add_candidates_dropdown {
  background: #18505a;
  padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.date_button:hover .add_candidates_dropdown, .date_button:focus .add_candidates_dropdown {
  display: block !important;
}

.add_candidates_dropdown>li {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.add_candidates_dropdown>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 15px;
  border-width: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #124c56 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}

.date_dropdown {
  padding: 0;
  display:block;
}

.date_dropdown>li {
  text-align: right;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  min-width: 130px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.date_dropdown>li>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.date_dropdown>li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.date_dropdown>li>a:hover,
.date_dropdown>li>a:focus {
  color: #eb3c29;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="candidates_header_btns">
  <li><a class="add_candidates" href="create-a-new-job.html"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Jobs</a></li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="date_button">Custom</a>
    <ul class="add_candidates_dropdown date_dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Department</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```